# Spark streaming, get x batch of window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm using pyspark to do some operations on 2 incoming streams.
Also I do window operations on both streams.

```
stream = ssc.  
streamW = stream.window(100,1)
```

for example.
One of the operations requires me to look at a specific batch inside **streamW** , so for example if the window length is 100, I want to look at the batch that is number 3 of the window.
More specifically I want to look at the first batch (ie: the batch that in next time interval is going to be removed from the window ).
Just to be clear: I want to get the batch leaving the window

Any ideas how to accomplish this ?

Comment: it's not clear whether you would like to get any batch (x) or only the batch of data leaving the window. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the batch leaving the window.